# Delete a contacts folder on an exchange server from a console application

Tags: c#, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I am trying to delete a folder with contacts on an exchange server. I'm doing this in a c# console application.

However when I use the deleteFolder method on the exchangeServiceBinding it returns the following message:

"Distinguished folders cannot be deleted."
Searching for the error results in the following: This error occurs when an attempt is made to delete a distinguished folder.

What is a "Distinguished folder" in exchange, how can a folder be a "Distinguished folder".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is one of the special folder and Outlook relies on it being in the mailbox. Outlook would not let you delete those folder either.
Other default folders are Inbox, Sent Items, Outbox, Drafts, Tasks, Calendar, Journal.